# What is CTAN.org now?

Tags: packages, fun, ctan

Today I clicked in this link in TeX StackExchange http://ctan.org/pkg/svg and I got this message (screenshot below).

**In particular, what does it mean that "Latex Productions International has acquired  the world wide exclusive rights from D.F.Knuth" !?**

Obviously ctan.org changed hands or something, **what happened to `ctan.org`?** 
**what would be a good link to use for TeX packages?**

[image: ctan]

Comment: Just weird, I got the same popup.  I think that page has been hacked.

Comment: Just check the date:)

Comment: Better keep the question here, for historical reasons... and so we don't fall again for the same!

Comment: And here I was thinking that a Microsoft shell company based out of Shanghai had acquired CTAN.

Comment: Did you note the name, "Donald **F** Knuth"?

Comment: The character means "insanity".  So there's a bit of clue to the joke.  Nice job, whoever wrote this up!

Comment: @A.Ellett if you hover the mouse over the symbol it says "cracy" (sic), (in line with all the other misspelled words.)

Comment: @AFeldman, why do you say "Microsoft shell company"?

Comment: It seems barbara had a hand in writing some, but not all, of the sentences. Either that, or some parts of the message are "official statements" and others are not. :-)

Comment: @alfC it was the "You can help latex to rule the World!" line at the end.  I didn't truly rule it out at first because of SourceForge http://www.techrepublic.com/article/its-time-to-go-away-sourceforge/ and https://opensource.com/business/16/3/when-selling-site-means-selling-community-part-2 I guess some of the funniest jokes poke at legitimate fears.

Comment: @PaulGessler -- no, barbara didn't have anything to do with it!  i only just now saw it when i logged in.  (it's still early morning here, and i'm allergic to mornings.)  check out http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb19-2/tb59hoax.pdf for an earlier instance of similar fun and games.

Comment: using Comic Sans would have make the joke more obvious!

Comment: I'd love to know what font that is!  https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont  doesn't recognize it :(

Comment: @oliver-dulac The font is Courgette (https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Courgette). It is free and can easily used in (Lua)TeX.

Comment: @GerdNeugebauer: many thanks! Really nice font :)

Comment: Hilarious! When I first read the announcement I went ballistic with anger. I neither took note of the date, nor the "F" in Knuth, and was of course oblivious to the meaning of the Chinese character. I feel like a fool. So glad it was a hoax!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It's currently Friday, April 1 in Europe. Happy April Fools' Day!

(Just in case you didn't know, [April 1st is a traditional day for people to play pranks on each other.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools%27_Day))

Comment: Also note that all links from the popup lead to unregistered domains. :-)

Comment: I was fooled as well by the popup, at the beginning!! :D  AhAhAh!! ;D  Nice joke!!  :)

Comment: In many countries the day of the practical jokes (if there are one)  is not  April 1.  Probably this day many people believed that CTAN was the last  hacked site as  some weeks ago happened with Linux Mint.

Answer (score 45):

Our webmaster Gerd Neugebauer invented this joke. He did a great job!

Manfred Lotz -- CTAN team

Comment: Really! Congratulations to Gerd!

Answer (score 12):

It's April Fools' Day.

The Chinese character 疯 actually means "crazy", "mad" or "insane".

Answer (score 7):

It caught me, I was livid and afraid to click onto anything, restarted all the usual things a couple of times. Good joke and nice to be caught out on April Fools! :) I got caught out by the 'Apple buys iFixit' joke a couple of years ago.