# CTAN popup on April 1, 2016

Tags: ctan, licensing

I went to CTAN.org and this huge message popped up on my browser.  I think I'm certain that it only applies for today, April, 1st 2016.  Can anyone confirm?

> Dearest customer, https://www.ctan.org/images/april2016/cracy.png we
>   are pleased to announce that we can offer our combined product range
>   at unbeatably low prices to you. Latex Productions International Ltd.,
>   Shanghai has acquired the world wide exclusive rights on tex from
>   Donald F. Knuth. Now we will join our forces with ctan and tug for
>   your benefits. We are also getting in contact with many other latex
>   user groups world wide. This will allow us to gain even more momentum
>   and offer an even further extended set of latex packages to you.
>   Please note that we intend to continue the presence of the former site
>   ctan.org. Nevertheless we would like to inform you that we will rename
>   it to Comprehensive Latex Artefact Novelties (CLAN) which is
>   considered more appropriate. Thus you will be redirected to our new
>   site soon. Keep on visiting this site in order not to miss the change
>   and the new packages with exiting and innovative latex artefacts. We
>   are looking forward for your orders of our high-quality products and
>   extended, long-term business relations. You can help latex to rule the
>   world! Latex Productions International Ltd., Shanghai Thank you

https://www.ctan.org/images/april2016/cracy.png[image]

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/301882/21344

Comment: Happy April Fools Day! ;D